# How to add my own code to replace navitagion bar (main menu)

Tags: magento2, menu, blank-theme

I have code **(html, css and js)** that make a navigation bar **(as main menu)** I want to put the `html, css and js` within the magento 2.3 **blank theme** (i already created a theme that inheritances from blank theme).

How do I add my **navbar** into new magento theme.